# Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq security exception

Tags: ninject, moq, ninject-2

I am using Ninject for my IoC container and I'm trying to write some unit tests.  I found the Ninject Mocking Kernel so I thought I'd give it a go but I can't get the simplest test to pass. I am missing something and need a little help.

Moq.4.0.10827.Final
Ninject-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0
Ninject.MockingKernel-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0

My unit test...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Constructor_CanInitialize()
    {
        var kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();

        var mock = kernel.Get<IDataRepository>(); <--Error here

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mock, typeof(DataRepository));
    }
```

Here is the error...

Test method TestFixture.Constructor_CanInitialize threw exception: 
System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq.MoqMockProvider.Create(Ninject.Activation.IContext)' to access security critical type 'Moq.Mock' failed.

Assembly 'Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

at Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq.MoqMockProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.mockingkernel\src\Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq\MoqMockProvider.cs: line 64
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs: line 157
at Ninject.KernelBase.b_*7(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs: line 375
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c*_DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs: line 179
at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs: line 147
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs: line 97
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Create>b__1(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs: line 81
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs: line 80
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs: line 157
at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs: line 375
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs: line 37
at TestFixture.Constructor_CanInitialize() in TestFixture.cs: line 32

Comment: I have narrowed this down to something in .Net v4.  If I use the v3.5 assemblies everything works as expected.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the following question.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055632/net-4-allowpartiallytrustedcallers-attribute-and-security-markings-like-securi

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting the same problem for a little while now. 
See this thread to follow my effort: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ninject/xInlcd2b1l8/discussion

Assuming that you are using NuGet you have two options:

- Don't use Ninject.MockingKernel right now or
- build it [from source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel) yourself.

Any way you may want to keep a tab on the project to use it via NuGet again once an updated version is available.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this works:

```
var mock = kernel.GetMock<IDataRepository>();
```