# Is there a way to override GetObjectData in custom exception class, without using APTCA?

Tags: c#, .net, code-access-security

I have a partially trusted AppDomain Sandbox, I execute method `X`, which instantiates MyException:

```
[Serializable]
class MyException: Exception
{
    public MyException():base("My exception") { }

    protected MyException(SerializationInfo serializationInfo, StreamingContext streamingContext)
        : base(serializationInfo, streamingContext) { }

    [SecurityCritical]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        Console.WriteLine("A line");
    }
}
```

Assembly `A`, which contains `MyException` is NOT loaded with full trust into the Sandbox. When `X` is executed in Sandbox, `TypeLoadException` occurs:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: MyException.GetObjectData .

I thought, that having `[SecurityCritical]` on `GetObjectData` is what it requires, but it appears to have no effect.

If I add `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` to `A`, and load `A` with full trust into Sandbox, this code works fine. However, `A` contains many classes, and I only face this problem with this particular `GetObjectData`.

Without reverting to older security models, is there a way to make `MyException` work without `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` and without loading it with full trust?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement Exception.GetObjectData in .NET 4 in a library assembly that has the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124874/how-do-i-implement-exception-getobjectdata-in-net-4-in-a-library-assembly-that)